# Records with the same datetime wrongly treated as different events

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a table of captures, which are time-stamped photos taken of different animals at different camera stations. I want to work out the visit frequency of each animal to each camera station, using a column NewVisit to mark the first record of each new visit.

For each record of a visit there could be one or several records of the same `AnimalID` at a `StationID`. `VisitStart` is the `cDateTime` of the earliest capture/record during each visit. Likewise, `VisitEnd` is the latest capture of the visit.

I have written the following query to mark records as a `New Visit` when they have the same `VisitStart` as the date of the record.

```
UPDATE Capture
    SET Capture.NewVisit = Yes
WHERE (((Capture.VisitStart)=Capture.cDateTime) And
       ((Capture.SurveyID)=1) And
       ((Capture.SpeciesID)=1));
```

This works fine for most visits, however sometimes there are multiple records with the exact same time stamp (this occurs when the camera takes a 3-photo-burst - 3 photos in quick succession). In this situation my query marks all 3 records as being a `NewVisit`.

Is there a way to stop this happening, by specifying that if there are >1 records with the same `StationID`, `SpeciesID`, `AnimalID` and `cDateTime` then `NewVisit` is only true for one of the records, e.g. the record with the lowest `CaptureID`.

Here's an example of my table after running the `NewVisit` query:

```
CaptureID   SurveyID    StationID   SpeciesID   AnimalID    TRANScDateTime       VisitStart             NewVisit
1307        1           5            1          5           15/07/2013 08:04:50  15/07/2013 08:04:50    TRUE
8172        1           5            1          2           15/07/2013 08:04:50  15/07/2013 08:04:50    TRUE
1306        1           5            1          2           15/07/2013 08:04:50  15/07/2013 08:04:50    TRUE
8173        1           5            1          2           15/07/2013 08:04:50  15/07/2013 08:04:50    TRUE
1308        1           5            1          2           15/07/2013 08:04:51  15/07/2013 08:04:50    FALSE
8174        1           5            1          5           15/07/2013 08:04:51  15/07/2013 08:04:50    FALSE
1309        1           5            1          5           15/07/2013 08:08:40  15/07/2013 08:04:50    FALSE
```

`CaptureID` is the primary key.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the query appropriately.  And your sample data has no field called `cDateTime` or `SpeciesId`.  Please fix the question so the data matches the query you are using.

Comment: Google "Update Top 1".   This question has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: The database is called Camera Base, MS Access 2010, free to download.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) Capture
    SET Capture.NewVisit = Yes
WHERE Capture.VisitStart=Capture.cDateTime
ORDER BY Capture.CaptureID,
         Capture.SurveyID,
         Capture.StationID,
         Capture.SpeciesID,
         Capture.AnimalID,
         Capture.TRANScDateTime;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are (sometimes) good, but code+explanation makes answers (most times) better.